# GlassFish Server works on Netbeans 7.2 but not on 7.3

Tags: netbeans, glassfish-3, netbeans-7.3

I have just installed Netbeans 7.3. Prepared a sample web application.
But Glassfish does not start. 
Error message is "....\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1036: Deployment error: GlassFish Server 3+ Server start failed. Cant create start proccess.
See the server log for details."

Unfortunately nothing in the server log.
I deleted domains folder and  server then recreated. Nothing changed. :(

Is it a bug related to http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=217228 ?

Any solution?

My system is 64 Bit Windows 7 with Turkish locale.
Web application is Primefaces based, JSF 2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is about language settings. 
You can change localization settings in the netBeans configuration file($NETBEANSHOME/etc/netbeans.conf).
Just add "--locale en" to end of the "netbeans_default_options" line.

Also you can start glassfish with asaadmin tool with following these steps.

1- execute C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\bin\asaadmin.bat
2- start-domain